# Trying to build a deep learning model for Weapon detection using X-ray photos , During model.fit it shows this ValueError

Tags: model, valueerror

Showing this value error while training (Could not find callback with key=pyfunc_140 in the registry.)

I re-installed tensorflow and removed the steps_per_epoch in order to remove this error but it keeps showing up

Code:

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsuRV.png)